# Debian 9 problem with crontab permissions

Tags: cron, debian-stretch

I installed Debian 9 on my VPS. I installed LAMP on the server. I'm logged in as root, I created a new site *"/var/www/example.com"* and I see that the permissions are "root:root". The web page is displayed in the browser.

I created a *cron.php* file that writes the current time to the file. In crontab I have **/usr/bin/php /var/www/example.com/cron.php**. If I run this command through the terminal, everything works. However, Crontab returns an error because it does not have write permissions. However, Crontab runs as root. The directory has 777 permissions.

I tried to set */var/www* as *www-data:www-data* and the same for crontab (crontab -u www-data -e). The result is the same, cron runs but does not write to the file.

EDIT:
I found that if the script contains: file_put_contents('output.txt', 'xxx'); the file created by cron is in root. If I set the full path, everything is fine: file_put_contents('/var/www/exmaple.com/output.txt', 'xxx'); Is there any way to modify this behavior?

Comment: As which user you run the cron job?

Comment: By default, as root.

Answer (score 0):

You can create sample script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc #or use .bash_profile
/usr/bin/php /var/www/example.com/cron.php >>/path/to/output
```

and add it as `cron` record:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/script/sh
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. CRON[9064]: (root) CMD (/var/www/example.com/console.sh), console.sh has permissions: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 138 Feb 27 20:44 console.sh. If I run from the terminal, it is written to the file, otherwise not.

Comment: I found that if the script contains: file_put_contents('output.txt', 'xxx'); the file created by cron is in root. If I set the full path, everything is fine: file_put_contents('/var/www/exmaple.com/output.txt', 'xxx'); Is there any way to modify this behavior?

Comment: You can run the script as different user which home is /var/www/exmaple.com. But why do not add full path in this call?